# Is there a monitoring endpoint for Spark Structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-synapse

In Spark's official docs, we see that there are monitoring endpoints for DStream like

> /streaming/statistics

[image]

However, there does not seem to be ones for structured streaming mentioned here. I'm looking                     to monitor streaming statistics for a structured streaming job.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html